# update rails app on EC2 instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Let me start by saying I don't have experience with rails + amazon server stuff.

I have to update one script for the application on Amazon EC2 instance (add one line of code to sidekiq worker).
In this sidekiq I am making request to another api but I need to update the `url` of this request.

Do I have to redeploy the whole app or I can do that without redeploying the whole application?

Comment: How do you usually deploy you app?

Comment: It was deployed with capistrano. I just want to know if I can add this line of code and the app will run because I don't see point in redeploying the whole thing if I need to just add one line. But I don't know if it's possible and will it work!

Comment: Then you have to deploy the whole thing again unless you want to ssh into the server and change that one file on production.

Comment: I can ssh in the server and change that one thing. I just wanted to know if it's possible to change that on production because I think it would be faster?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You **might** have to restart the application though.

Answer (score 1):

Although changing the app manually through ssh I recommend you change your app in whatever source code control you are using (git, mecurial, svn) and then redeploy using Capistrano.

Comment: won't it break the database?